# Setting Map values

Tags: lightning

I have several duallistbox. I want to Map all the options I have selected from all duallistbox. All duallistbox is created dynamically.

```
 $A.createComponent(
            "lightning:dualListbox",
            {
                "aura:id": apiName,
                "label": name + " Options (OPTIONAL):",
                "sourceLabel": "Options",
                "selectedLabel": "Selected",
                //"value": selectedBoxValuex,
                "options": subOptons,
                "onchange" : component.getReference("c.collectValues")
            },
```

Here is client-side controller which is not working:

```
   collectValues: function (component, event) {
        var selectedOptionValues = event.getParam("value");
        var listMap = new Map();  //will overwrite the old map
        var a = event.getSource();
        var boxId = a.getLocalId(); //aura:id from duallistbox
        listMap.set(boxId, selectedOptionValues);
        console.log("Try to get value using this key value: ", listMap);
        for (var [key, value] of listMap) {
            console.log('here is the key', key, ' and values ', value, ' and the map ', listMap);
        }

    }
```

The problem here is, the map will always be overwritten after I change something from duallistbox. what I want is adding always a new Map where the key is the ID and value would be a list of selected options. I think the reasons is because I always recall the function when i change something. How should I do it then? Any suggestions? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly, You can not achieve this. but you can achieve this by using javascript hack.

you can add a property in `component` variable like `component["listMap"]`

Update Code:

```
collectValues: function (component, event) {
    var selectedOptionValues = event.getParam("value");
    if(!component["listMap"])
        component["listMap"] = new Map();
    var a = event.getSource();
    var boxId = a.getLocalId(); //aura:id from duallistbox
    component["listMap"].set(boxId, selectedOptionValues);
    console.log("Try to get value using this key value: ", component["listMap"]);
    for (var [key, value] of component["listMap"]) {
        console.log('here is the key', key, ' and values ', value, ' and the map ', component["listMap"]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it's working. Do you know where I can find a good documentation about this Javascript hack?

Comment: One more question... Is it possible to set component["listMap"] as a aura:attribute value?  if i got something like this     <aura:attribute name="skillsFilterMap" type="Map" />

Comment: No, It will not work with <aura:attribute>. it only work in component controller.

Comment: Is there any way that I can make it work with <aura:attribute>?

Comment: Yup, you can create a aura attribute but you have set value every time in the method.